# .htaccess - Password in one folder, excepting all sub-folders

Tags: .htaccess, password-protection

I have a folder named "adminhide", wich is inside the folder "forum" and which should be password protected. In the folder "adminhide", I have more than 50 sub-folders and all those sub-folders should not be password protected.

The .htaccess file should be placed in the folder "adminhide", or in the folder "forum".

Example:

```
forum/adminhide: protected
forum/adminhide/js: unprotected
forum/adminhide/js/something: unprotected
forum/adminhide/images: unprotected
forum/adminhide/something: unprotected
```

Here is what I have now:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "admin"
AuthUserFile "/home/xgclanco/.htpasswds/public_html/xg-clan.pt/forum/adminhide/passwd"
require valid-user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by placing a .htaccess file in the subdirectories that you want to exclude with the "Allow from all" directive.

.htaccess works down from the current directory, so if you included .htaccess in a subdirectory containing:

```
Allow from all
```

You will get the desired result.

You could also achieve this by specifying just the individual files you would like to protect in the adminhide folder by doing this in your htaccess file:

```
AuthUserFile "/home/xgclanco/.htpasswds/public_html/xg-clan.pt/forum/adminhide/passwd"

AuthName "admin"

AuthType Basic

<Files "index.php">

  require valid-user

</Files>
```

Comment: I have a lot of sub-folders, there is no other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

All subfolders below the one you put your .htaccess-file in are automaticly protected. I think there is no way to change that.

So you either have to change your folder structure or put the stuff you want to pretect somewhere else.